# Random Sampling from Distribution

Tags: distributions, sampling, beta-distribution

I have data of lengths ranging from 25 to 135 and I would like to determine the distribution of this data so that I can randomly generate values from this distribution. My data contains 443 values, and I would like to generate thousands of values, so I want to determine the distribution rather than randomly sampling my data.

Using the "fitdistrplus" package, my data appears to fit the beta distribution, but my values are not bounded by (0,1) so I am unsure how to interpret this. How can I determine the distribution that fits this data and randomly sample it?

```
library(fitdistrplus)
x<-c(51.4, 44.9, 52.7, 37, 26.2, 56, 89.5, 30.7, 26.1, 98.1, 49.3, 87.3, 54.1, 49.7, 80.6, 39, 97.6, 76.4, 42.8, 44, 97, 34.8, 27, 42.4, 50.5, 58.1, 61.6, 36.6, 123.1, 25.3, 95.4, 78.4, 73.7, 28.3, 83.8, 38.9, 43.9, 49.3, 85.3, 39, 76.8, 54.4, 70.7, 93.9, 44.4, 32.9, 25.5, 45.5, 99.3, 38.4, 67.2, 34.1, 65.7, 37.3, 60.2, 34.8, 73.5, 72.9, 76.9, 30, 90.3, 38.5, 45.8, 28.3, 28.8, 62.2, 43.8, 45.2, 33.2, 35.1, 50.2, 61.2, 77.3, 30, 63, 115.4, 54, 26.2, 60.4, 52.1, 58.7, 85.1, 43.7, 25, 39.2, 83.9, 32.3, 44.2, 50.7, 54.5, 59.2, 80.3, 45.9, 55.4, 29.6, 48, 31.2, 61.3, 60.1, 60.3, 43.2, 40.9, 60, 28.3, 36.7, 31.4, 68.8, 63.8, 50.2, 40.4, 53, 56.8, 49.8, 71.2, 48.7, 34.2, 36.5, 56.9, 43.5, 31.8, 32, 33.4, 66.2, 72.5, 74, 56.9, 71.5, 79.6, 52.7, 67.8, 41.4, 65.5, 78, 77.7, 70.9, 78.4, 102, 78.8, 109.9, 31.1, 72, 44.2, 57.4, 55.5, 50.5, 33.2, 78.9, 59.6, 88.3, 33.9, 60.7, 29.3, 61.9, 47.2, 120.4, 89.7, 81.1, 135.1, 70.6, 46, 67.5, 32.7, 82, 30.6, 75.9, 32.3, 35.7, 84.4, 59.1, 58, 76.7, 36.8, 30.8, 29.1, 50.5, 43.2, 40.5, 28.2, 112.6, 44.8, 56.7, 50.4, 92.1, 38, 70.9, 51.8, 87.8, 59.7, 66.2, 54.5, 41.7, 104.8, 36, 54.6, 57.6, 34.8, 47, 75, 44.1, 72.5, 53.1, 77.7, 46.5, 92.2, 33.6, 102.2, 56.5, 30.3, 53.8, 85.3, 39.9, 27.7, 105.4, 41.2, 33.2, 28.6, 42.9, 34.2,  33.1, 70.3, 37.2, 61.9, 56.8, 65.5, 86.7, 37.1, 118.3, 94.3,  81.5, 56.5, 80.3, 50.4, 36, 27.8, 41.1, 83.2, 39.6, 36.5, 35.7, 112.4, 101.8, 71.2, 63.5, 80.1, 39.9, 56.5, 68.9, 81.4, 91.8, 69.4, 37.5, 65.6, 95.1, 49.8, 31.3, 59.2, 38, 88.7, 64.6, 112.6, 59, 60.6, 110.9, 63.8, 55.1, 57.1, 99.6, 63.4, 64.2, 104, 94.8, 25.9, 28.2, 40.3, 96.1, 55.5, 67, 45.1, 126.4, 43.4, 72, 96.9,  47.5, 48.1, 27, 67.6, 67.5, 26.1, 26.1, 130.3, 40.4, 121, 63.6,  79, 103.7, 91.9, 28.6, 29.2, 27.5, 26.3, 103.1, 130.5, 48.3,  48.7, 61.7, 40.6, 85.8, 93.1, 63.3, 32.1, 63.3, 54.1, 123, 95.4,  46.9, 72.1, 112, 65.4, 44.5, 77.5, 60.1, 38.7, 82.2, 54.5, 31.5,  28, 74.3, 31.4, 71.6, 51.1, 88.4, 50.3, 44.3, 25.3, 64.8, 79.4,  43.3, 87.5, 53.4, 45.7, 95.9, 57.7, 40.8, 110.8, 63.4, 31.5,  39, 106.8, 73.2, 91.2, 80.1, 44, 73, 65.5, 87.5, 52.2, 42.1,  99.2, 62.9, 27.2, 47.7, 58.5, 31.5, 29, 73.7, 129.3, 91.3, 62.1,  66.5, 91.8, 30.3, 61.7, 31, 50.4, 40.6, 45.7, 29, 37.4, 72.1,  44.4, 91, 31.3, 64.8, 70.2, 86.1, 42, 27.1, 31.4, 62.8, 73.4,  52.4, 67.7, 70.2, 112.2, 68.9, 96.9, 70.3, 51.6, 31.9, 73.5,  69.7, 33.2, 77.3, 100.6, 59.2, 28.5, 72.2, 74, 46.6, 83, 30.3, 36.9, 37.4, 46.9, 64.8, 38.6, 58, 53.9, 42.3, 33.7, 25.6, 92.9,  26.9, 31.3, 90.3, 64.8, 82.1, 114.8, 32.8, 48.6, 36.1, 56.8, 40.1, 54.2, 86.3, 56.9, 42.1, 31, 38.9, 28.9, 55.8, 110.6, 39.9)

descdist(x, discrete = FALSE)
```

[image: output of descdist]

Comment: You can sample (with replacement) directly from from your data values by using something like this `simsA<- sample(x, 2000, replace=TRUE)` though this will give you many duplicates. You already have those: $33.2$ and $64.8$ each appear four times in your data.  If instead you want values interpolated in the distribution then something like `simsB <- as.vector(quantile(x, runif(2000)))` might meet your needs.

Comment: Or `jitter(sample(x, 2000, replace=TRUE))` if you want to generate values that have not been seen before.  (You might want to play with the arguments to `jitter()` if the defaults give you not enough or too much randomness.)

Answer (score 1):

1. The purpose of this form of the Pearson plot is that it can help identify a distribution from a class of distributions[1], but each sub-family is only identified in the diagram up to multiplication by scale, a change of sign[2], and a location shift.

   Which is to say the distribution it's actually suggesting you consider, Pearson type I, is *not* limited to support on (0,1). In effect you're dealing with a four-parameter beta.

   Be warned, however, that sample kurtosis tends to be biased downward, much more so the larger the population kurtosis; even if it were plausible that your sample were drawn from the Pearson class[3] it's not automatically a great way to choose which subfamily generated your data.
2. You have not discussed why it needs to be a named distribution that you use to sample from. If you need to sample from a distribution that looks like your sample, you might consider resampling the data, perhaps.
3. Another alternative would be to sample from some nonparametric approximation, such as a kernel density estimator (which are particularly simple to sample from).
4. It often (but not always) turns out - once the intended use of such sampling is made explicit - that the user is effectively posting an XY-problem. There's often a better approach that this sampling of a fictional distribution was intended to solve.

---

[1]: However this form of Pearson plot adds a few other distributions to the diagram from outside the Pearson family

[2]: The potential for a change of sign is not needed for the type I region but is important when considering the other regions to the right of $0$ skewness$^2$, such as the type III (shifted gamma).

[3]: Your "true" population distribution will not have any simple form. Not Pearson family, nor any other distribution with a name. Simple distributional models are approximations, potentially useful fictions, not facts about the world.